# How to import modules from a folder and add them into a Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, plugins

I imported modules from plugins folder using importlib module:

```
plugin_files = os.listdir("plugins")
for plugin_file in plugin_files:
   importlib.import_module(plugin_file)
```

How can I add those modules into a list `plugins = list()` so when I loop through them I can call their function that they share in common(interface)? For example:

```
for plugin in plugins:
   plugin.send_notification()
```

I tried to look into documentation of importlib module, however, I see nothing about grouping and listing modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these should work.

```py
plugin_files = os.listdir("plugins")
plugins = []
for plugin_file in plugin_files:
    plugins.append(importlib.import_module(plugin_file))

for plugin in plugins:
    plugin.send_notification()
```

OR

```py
plugins = list(map(importlib.import_module,os.listdir("plugins")))
for plugin in plugins:
    plugin.send_notification()
```

Quick test below:

```py
class test:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

plugins = list(map(test,['bob','jim']))

for plugin in plugins:
    print(plugin.name)
```

```
bob
jim
```

Comment: Thank you! Your method of just appending returns to list works. Only thing I forgot to add is sys.path.append("./plugins"), now it works just as intended. EDIT: Oh and just for future reference, when importing module names, I think ".py" needs to be stripped down.